# how to upload image from gallery using fragment

Tags: android, fragment

we have this code for activity ... but we need to implement this in fragment

we had try but application crash on `Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();` line of code

plzz help me !!!!

**Code :**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private TextView messageText;
    private Button uploadButton, btnselectpic;
    private ImageView imageview;
    private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    private String upLoadServerUri = null;
    private String imagepath=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        btnselectpic = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_selectpic);
        messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_pic);

        btnselectpic.setOnClickListener(this);
        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        upLoadServerUri = "http://10.0.2.2/newapp/UploadToServer.php";
        ImageView img= new ImageView(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(arg0==btnselectpic)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);
        }
        else if (arg0==uploadButton) {

             dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
             messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {

                      uploadFile(imagepath);

                 }
               }).start();     
        }

    } 

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath(); 

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" +imagepath);

        }
    }
         public String getPath(Uri uri) {
                String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


          String fileName = "ReplacedwithUserid.jpg";

          HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;  
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";
          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
          File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

          if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

               dialog.dismiss(); 

               Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+imagepath);

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ imagepath);
                   }
               }); 

               return 0;

          }
          else
          {
               try { 

                     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                   URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                   // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                   conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                   conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                   conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); //replaced with fileName
                   //conn.setRequestProperty(field, newValue);
                   dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                             + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                   // create a buffer of  maximum size
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                   // read file and write it into form...
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                   while (bytesRead > 0) {

                     dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                    }

                   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                   String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                   Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                           + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                   if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                      +" C:/wamp/www/newapp/uploads";
                                messageText.setText(msg);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });                
                   }    

                   //close the streams //
                   fileInputStream.close();
                   dos.flush();
                   dos.close();

              } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  ex.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });

                  Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
              } catch (Exception e) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  e.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });
                  Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e);  
              }
              dialog.dismiss();       
              return serverResponseCode; 

           } // End else block 
         }
}
```

logcat:

08-08 01:50:22.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1103): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-08 01:50:22.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1103): Process: in.acsg, PID: 1103
08-08 01:50:22.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1103): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:1, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/42 }} to activity {in.acsg/in.acsg.HomeScrren}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-08 01:50:22.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)
08-08 01:50:22.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
08-08 01:50:22.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-08 01:50:22.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
08-08 01:50:22.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-08 01:50:22.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-08 01:50:22.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-08 01:50:22.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-08 01:50:22.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-08 01:50:22.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-08 01:50:22.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-08 01:50:22.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-08 01:50:22.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1103): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-08 01:50:22.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at in.acsg.mainScreen.Publish.getPath(Publish.java:124)
08-08 01:50:22.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at in.acsg.mainScreen.Publish.onActivityResult(Publish.java:109)
08-08 01:50:22.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5427)
08-08 01:50:22.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
08-08 01:50:22.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     ... 11 more
08-08 01:50:27.366: I/Choreographer(1173): Skipped 118 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-08 01:50:28.186: D/dalvikvm(1173): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 201K, 9% free 2986K/3272K, paused 39ms, total 40ms

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Post a stack trace so that we can see the error you are getting.

Comment: Check: [onActivityResult not being called in Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

onActivityResult() does not get called in Fragment.

Try,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);
```

make sure your parent activity is extending FragmentActivity
override onActivityResult() in your FragmentActivity

Below are the snippets from my app
(in my fragment class)

```
private void captureImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        imageURI = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageURI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

(in my parent activity)

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The fragment lives within an activity, so you can delegate the job to the activity, you have Activity (A) that holds fragment (B), and you would like to upload a picture from within fragment (B), but the onActivityResult life cycle hook isn't being triggered from the fragment(B), so you can create an interface (C) that has a method, which when is triggered will trigger the onActivityResult life cycle hook within the activity that holds the fragment

in other words:

1. Interface (C) will have a method called pleaseUploadPicture();
2. Activity (A) will implement this method, in which it will trigger onActivityResult, because (A) is an activity
3. Inside fragment (B), create a variable "interfaceCReference" that hold a reference to (C) interface, override the onAttach method to set the value of the (C) interface reference "  interfaceCReference  = (C) context; "
4. Inside fragment (B), OnClick @ the upload button, make the interfaceCReference call pleaseUploadPicture method " interfaceCReference .pleaseUploadPicture(); "